# Atualizar linha do console

Tags: python, console

Tenho um loop em python, e gostaria de informar o valor de uma variavel a cada vez que ela é atualizada, porém **não quero sujar o console** dando print toda vez e **nem limpar todo o console**.

Existe uma maneira de eu obter este resultado?

```
print("Executando processo:")
while True:
    a = a +1
    print a
```

**O resultado ao final de 3 interações é:**

Interação 1:

```
$ - Executando processo: 
$ - 1
```

Interação 2:

```
$ - Executando processo:
$ - 1 
$ - 2
```

Interação 3:

```
$ - Executando processo:
$ - 1 
$ - 2
$ - 3
```

**E gostaria de obter o seguinte resultado:**

Interação 1:

```
$ - Executando processo:
$ - 1
```

Interação 2:

```
$ - Executando processo:
$ - 2
```

Interação 3:

```
$ - Executando processo:
$ - 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa o caractere de retorno de carro `\r`.

```py
import time

print('=== Executando ===')

for i in range(1, 11):
    print('- Processo:', i, end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)  # só para dar tempo de ver a mudança no console

print('=== Encerrado ===')
```

---

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return

> ...faz com que uma impressora ou o dispositivo de saída (geralmente o monitor) mova a posição do cursor para a primeira posição da linha onde se encontra.

Comment: É importante salientar que este processo só funciona se o novo texto for maior ou igual ao anterior. Se não for, caracteres do último texto permanecerão sendo exibidos, pois `\r` apenas retorna o cursor para o início da linha, mas não apaga seu conteúdo. Se no sistema não houver esta garantia, a melhor solução é utilizar a que apresentei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211832/atualizar-linha-do-console#comment433180_211832).

Comment: Eu ia adicionar espaços em branco pra evitar isso, mas achei que iria complicar desnecessariamente o entendimento.

Comment: Assim que eu chegar no PC edito a resposta a abranger esse caso